# Reference request: Dictionary of the Leibniz notation

Tags: reference-request, notation

Is there any published, somewhat comprehensive, list of (almost?) all the many ways in which the Leibniz notation ($dx,$ $P(dx),$ $d\mu(x),$ $du\wedge dv,$ etc., etc.) gets used in the various areas of mathematics?

(I posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3783281/dictionary-of-the-leibniz-notation) on m.s.e. and it was closed although nobody verbally expressed any specific objections to it or even hinted at such.)

Comment: from what I read on MSE it was closed as not being clear enough --- I'm not sure that asking the same question here will be helpful.

Comment: It's also clearly not research level (although lots of also clearly-not-research-level historical questions do well on MO anyway).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker : Do you have any guesses as to what someone might find unclear about this?

Comment: At least for me, the question is not clear since there is a distinction between, for example: the original notation used by Leibniz; the formalization of this notation (Robinson et al.); the derived notations inspired by the concept of differential in other branches, etc. Perhaps you could be more specific in what aspects are you interested about this.

Comment: @EFinat-S : Well, you've managed to surprise me at least. That there are great differences among those something I had to be acutely aware of in order to think of asking this question. And if I were to specify something like either the original usage of Leibniz or the formalization by Robinson, etc., then nothing would be left of the question at all. It's as if you had told someone who's driving to a destination that it's possible to run the car's engine without going anywhere, so why not do that instead?

Comment: My intention was not to offend you. Also, I'm not a native speaker of english, so it is sometimes difficult to make me understand. Perhaps its the phrase "gets used" what does not seems clear (at least to me): historically? formally? simply as an "abuse" of notation?

Comment: @EFinat-S : "Abuse of notation" is a bit of jargon that mathematicians use too much. I wonder whether there are any "abuses of notation" that are not in fact good notation. They are called abuses only because codified formalisms do not countenance them. The possibility that those formalisms are less than the whole truth should be considered. At any rate what I had in mind has more to do with what Leibniz and Robinson have in common.

Comment: "At any rate what I had in mind has more to do with what Leibniz and Robinson have in common". If you have that in mind, well, ask that.

Comment: @EFinat-S : As far as I know, I did.

Comment: @EFinat-S : Maybe something I said above in comments can be made clearer: It is _precisely_ the fact that there are such great differences as the one example that you cite that is the occasion for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure in which direction you are hoping for an answer, but to set a first data point I offer the [Pantheon of Derivatives](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/the-pantheon-of-derivatives-i/)

Part 1 – Directional Derivatives
Part 2 – Manifolds
Part 3 – Vector Bundles
Part 4 – Lie Theory
Part 5 – Theorems

Comment: Maybe this is similar to what I had in mind. (Every day I am appalled by the frequent crude typesetting solecisms in MathJax and LaTeX by otherwise literate mathematicians, and these pages are consistent with that. At one point I see $2\mathrm{max}\Big\{ \cdots\cdots\Big\}$ instead of $2\max\Big\{\cdots \cdots \Big\}$ and wonder why people don't know about things like this. But the content looks very interesting otherwise.)